# How i can update my cocoa repo?

Tags: cocoapods, xcode8, auth0

Im trying to use the version > 1.24 of Lock (https://github.com/auth0/Lock.iOS-OSX), but my cocoa repo has not available this version. I execute pod search Lock and i see the follow info:

```
Lock (1.13.0)
   A library that uses Auth0 for Authentication with Native Look & Feel
   pod 'Lock', '~> 1.13.0'
   - Homepage: https://github.com/auth0/Lock.iOS-OSX
   - Source:   https://github.com/auth0/Lock.iOS-OSX.git
   - Versions: 1.13.0, 1.12.1, 1.12.0, 1.11.3, 1.11.2, 1.11.1
```

The version in the repo is 1.27, and my repo is old. I try to update using pod repo update but still unavailable 
¿Someone can help me?

[image]

Im trying to use this podfile:

```
# Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
platform :ios, '10.0'

target 'TalkClassTest' do
  # Comment this line if you're not using Swift and don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!

  # Pods for TalkClassTest

  target 'TalkClassTestTests' do
   inherit! :search_paths
    pod 'Lock', '~> 1.24'
  end
end
```

but when i execute pod install i obtain this erros:

```
[!] Unable to satisfy the following requirements:

- `Lock (~> 1.24)` required by `Podfile`

None of your spec sources contain a spec satisfying the dependency: `Lock (~> 1.24)`.

You have either:
 * out-of-date source repos which you can update with `pod repo update`.
 * mistyped the name or version.
 * not added the source repo that hosts the Podspec to your Podfile.

Note: as of CocoaPods 1.0, `pod repo update` does not happen on `pod install` by default.
MacBook-Air-de-Randall:TalkClassTest Randal$
```

Comment: what does your pod file look like?

Comment: @DavidSeek i update the question with my podfile and the error that i obtain. Sorry but im beginner heh

Comment: `pod repo update`?

Comment: 1.27 seems to be the latest release. Perhaps put that in your profile instead of 1.24

Comment: also you just hit `pod install` not `pod repo install`

Comment: just delete `, '~> 1.24`, run `pod install` and then `pod update`

Comment: deleting , '~> 1.24 i obtain the error: [!] Unable to find a specification for `libextobjc (~> 0.4)` depended upon by `Lock`

Comment: thank to everyone, the solution applied is execute the follow commands:
    pod repo remove master
    pod setup

Comment: @randall, add that solution as an answer and mark it as accepted (it's okay to accept your own answers, as long as they fixed the issue), this way if someone else experiences the same issue it's easier to find the solution.

Answer (score 1):

thank to everyone, the solution applied is execute the follow commands: pod repo `remove master` and after `pod setup`